# Illustrator: Opacity Mask doesn't scale (i.e. follow vector art when scaling up/down)

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Something weird occurred, in which the opacity mask (the texture) doesn't scale when resizing the motif. I can't recall what setting affects the behavior for opacity masks.

All is Ok; as in, the opacity mask is *there* allright, and I can move it, etc. It just won't follow the vector paths when scaling them up. The opacity mask image is not locked either … very strange.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure your mask is linked.  If there's no link symbol in between the object and the mask on the Transparency palette, it's not linked.

[image]

Comment: That will do it every time. Same thing in Photoshop, too.

Comment: Thanks, Farray. Your answer is the right answer to my question. However, in my case, the mask was actually linked. Turns out what caused this behaviour was the fact that I had duplicate layers with the same mask/texture file. One being hidden. When I deleted the hidden layer (which used the same opacity mask/texture, the first layer's opacity mask began to scale together with the artwork. Anyway, problem gone.